# How to start WebLogic server using Java code

Tags: java, weblogic

I want to start weblogic server using Java code and have tried many options.
In my machine the startWebLogic.cmd file is at location

D:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ass1\startWebLogic.cmd

Can any one please help me with the code that runs this cmd file please?

```
import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Map.Entry;
    public class StartWLClass 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            System.out.println("1");
            String cmdFileName="startWebLogic.cmd";
            String cmdDirectoryPath="D:\\Oracle\\Middleware\\user_projects\\domains\\ass1";
            System.out.println("2");
            File file=new File(cmdDirectoryPath);
            System.out.println("3");
            Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
            try 
            {
                System.out.println("4");
                //runtime.exec("cmd /C " + cmdFileName, getEnvironmentVariables(), file);
                runtime.exec("cmd /C " + cmdFileName, getEnvironmentVariables(), file);
                System.out.println("5");
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("6");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    private static String[] getEnvironmentVariables() 
    {
            final Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
            System.out.println(env);
            final String[] result = new String[env.size()];
            final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(100);
            int i = 0;
            for (Entry<String, String> e : env.entrySet()) 
            {
              buf.setLength(0);
              result[i++] = buf.append(e.getKey()).append('=').append(e.getValue()).toString();
            }
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
          }
    }
```

Comment: I have found a solution to this question. The code goes as under.

    String filePath = "D:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/ass1/startWebLogic.cmd";
        try 
        {
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start D:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/ass1/startWebLogic.cmd",null);
        } 
        
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this question. The code goes as under.

```
String filePath = "D:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/ass1/startWebLogic.cmd";
    try 
    {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start D:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/ass1/startWebLogic.cmd",null);
    } 

    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: mark as a answer, in left side see one tick symbol is there.